# Maven fails to find io.reactivex.subjects in terminal, succeeds in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, terminal

In attempting to prepare a personal project for Gitlab CI, I've stumbled across an issue where maven cannot find the `io.reactivex.subjects` package in the terminal, and as a result, compilation fails like so:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ spell-idle ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 24 source files to /home/aschaefer/dev/spell-idle/target/classes
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project spell-idle: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/aschaefer/dev/spell-idle/src/com/aps/spells/rx/GuiSubjects.java:[5,29] package io.reactivex.subjects does not exist
[ERROR] /home/aschaefer/dev/spell-idle/src/com/aps/spells/rx/GuiSubjects.java:[6,29] package io.reactivex.subjects does not exist
[ERROR] /home/aschaefer/dev/spell-idle/src/com/aps/spells/rx/GuiSubjects.java:[14,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Subject
[ERROR]   location: class com.aps.spells.rx.GuiSubjects
[ERROR] /home/aschaefer/dev/spell-idle/src/com/aps/spells/rx
```

Here's the arguably relevant part of the pom. If anything else is needed, let me know and I'll edit it in:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxjavafx</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
... (other dependencies here)
</dependencies>
```

I've been running various combinations of commands like `mvn clean install` or `mvn compile test` but it doesn't seem to help.

Eclipse version of maven is 3.5.3, system version is 3.5.2.

I don't have a settings.xml in the ~/.m2 directory.

Thanks in advance for any help offered!

Comment: Have you checked if the maven of eclipse is the same that used in your system? With the same configuration?

Comment: The versions are a little different: my terminal version is 3.5.2, my Eclipse is 3.5.3. I'll add that info to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

As you say that in eclipse is working, go to `Preferences>Maven>user settings` there you will see the eclipse mvn configuration and compare it with the one on your system normally in `~/.m2/settings.xml` or by the environment variable `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`

Comment: Strangely enough, I don't have a settings.xml in the ~/.m2 directory. I'll have a look and see if there's other places where a settings.xml might exist.

Comment: But have you checked the configuration and version of maven used by eclipse?

Comment: I edited the OP with the version of maven that Eclipse uses; it's a subversion ahead of my system maven. As for the configuration, it doesn't seem to deviate at all from standard settings one gets after installing the maven eclipse plugin.

Comment: When you compile in terminal, are you in the same folder than when you compile in eclipse? Are you sure that you are using the same pom.xml?